# Can't register Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, xna

Quite a time ago, I made an app for Windows Phone using XNA on VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone and didn't register it.
Now when I try to open VS 2012 Express, it asks me for registration, with the link "Register online", but this link is broken. It gets me to an error message.

How can I register VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone now? If there is no way, so how can I develop for Windows Phone using XNA nowadays using, say, VS 2013?

Answer (score 1):

The express editions of VS are gone, you should try downloading the community edition, it's a fully featured VS, although I don't know if you can use XNA on top of it!
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the projects offered by VS Community 2015 and I was not able to find an XNA project template. The oldest phone you can develop for is Windows Phone 8. It also has Windows Phone Silverlight templates.
If you want to develop games on WP8 I can recommend you [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/)

Comment: The only problem is that I just need to run and deploy an existing XNA Project to my phone. I can't start a new Project.